# File watch in the directory using Python and then send data using POST request on file modification

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, watchdog, python-watchdog

I want to watch two different Directory for excel file modification(timestamp) and after modification I want to call one API HTTP Post request to one endpoint, I have already wrote below code using Python Watchdog and requests library, but facing two error in the same.

Problem 1:- event(event.event_type == 'modified') is getting trigger two times on one file modification, which causing to send two post data request. So what is the correct event type to watch file modification in watchdog library, which will make this conditional code to true only once.

Problem 2:- In the 'Watcher' class, in function 'start' I am not able to assign Handler() value to the event_handler variable. what mistake I am making here ?

please guide me to fix this or any other better approach. thank you in an advance

```
    import time 
from time import sleep
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import os
from collections import defaultdict

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def __init__(self, path):
        super().__init__()
        self.path = path   
        self.files = defaultdict(lambda:0)     

    def on_modified(self, event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif (event.event_type == 'modified' and event.src_path.endswith('.csv')):
                # api_url = 'http://10.166.72.3:8080/promo/summary?userId=abc'
                stats = os.stat(event.src_path).st_ctime
                sleep(5)
                if stats - self.files[event.src_path] > 1:
                    df = pd.read_csv(self.path)
                    df1 = df.to_json(orient='records')
                    df1.replace("\\","")
                    print(df1)

        self.files[event.src_path] = stats
                #r = requests.post(url=api_url, json=df1)
                #print(r.status_code, r.reason, r.text)


class Watcher:

    def __init__(self, directory, handler):
        self.directory = directory
        self.handler = handler
        self.observer = Observer()

    def start(self):
        #event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule( self.handler, self.directory, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.observer.stop()

    def join(self):
        self.observer.join()

if __name__ == '__main__': 

    handler1 = Handler('C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\Desktop\\OCR_RPA\\FirstOCR\\Diageo\\Output\\InvoiceMasterData.csv')
    handler2 = Handler('C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\Desktop\\OCR_RPA\\SecondOCR\\Diageo\\Output\\AgreementMasterData.csv')

    w1 = Watcher("C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\Desktop\\OCR_RPA\\FirstOCR\\Diageo\\Output", handler1) 
    w2 = Watcher("C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\Desktop\\OCR_RPA\\SecondOCR\\Diageo\\Output", handler2) 

    w1.start() 
    w2.start() 

    try:
       while True:
           time.sleep(5)
    except:
        w1.stop() 
        w2.stop() 
        print("Error")

    w1.join() 
    w2.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1: Event "modified" fired twice**

This issue appears because multiple operations can occur when you save a file, data are changed, then the metadata (last modified ...). It can be hard to handle depending on what you need and the frequency of changes if there are many users.

First you should limit the files watched by testing the extension to avoid temporary files and all other formats. Then i suggest to save the last time of modification of the file to be able to compare it between two events, and fire the API call only if the delay is over X seconds.

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # this dict will store the filenames and the time
        self.files = defaultdict(lambda:0)

    def on_any_event(self, event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif (event.event_type == 'modified' and 
              event.src_path.endswith(('.xls','.xlsx'))) :

            # here we get the last change timestamp 
            stats = os.stat(event.src_path).st_mtime

            # delay of 1 sec minimum between 2 changes
            # self.files[event.src_path] is set to 0 thanks to the defaultdict
            if stats - self.files[event.src_path] > 1: 
                print('api call with ', event.src_path)
                # do what you need

            # then update the time for this file
            self.files[event.src_path] = stats
```

---

**Problem 2: Pass handler parameter**

You get an error when you instantiate `Handler()` because you create a parameter `path` in the contructor :

```
class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def __init__(self, path):
        super().__init__()
        self.path = path
```

It seems you don't use it inside `Handler`, maybe you could remove this parameter ? Otherwise just give the path you want to handle like :

```
def start(self):
    event_handler = Handler(self.directory) # or Handler() if you remove path
    self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.directory, recursive=True)
    self.observer.start()
```

Comment: I have solved the Problem 2, and in Problem 1: Event "modified" fired twice - some what it is working fine, now it is executing the code only once, but only first modification in the file, when I am making second modification in any of my file after 5 or 10min as well, then also it got blocked in some condition. as in my below code I am watching two directory, so it is working fine for first edit in the both file, but when I am making second attempt on any of these files then It is not giving me any response or my API post execution.

Comment: This is the modified code after making changes as per your suggestion-                                  
class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, path):
        super().__init__()
        self.path = path   
        self.files = defaultdict(lambda:0)     
    def on_modified(self, event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None
        elif (event.event_type == 'modified' and event.src_path.endswith('.csv')):
                sleep(5)
                if stats - self.files[event.src_path] > 1:
                    df = pd.read_csv(self.path)

Comment: df1 = df.to_json(orient='records')
                    print(df1)
                self.files[event.src_path] = stats

Comment: This condition is giving me 0,.,on every run, even after 10 or 15min later,.,which causing to not run on third attempt  :-      if stats - self.files[event.src_path] > 1:

Comment: Alright, i can check this later. Please can you update your post to append the new code?

Comment: I'm not sure about  st_ctime stat, can you try with `st_mtime` ? `stats = os.stat(event.src_path).st_mtime`

Comment: yes that st_mtime worked perfectly, I also figure that out after posting the latest code in the evening, I thought to inform you now, but you also find it now, thank you so much, that approached help me,.,.,good learning with this :)

Comment: Glad to help you for that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can check file change watcher module from this link:

https://github.com/NVISO-BE/binsnitch

then make your own alert feed back.